# How to create a list of HubTile items that scrolls

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

I am populating a listbox full of HubTile items dynamically, but the list does not scroll down on the emulator or my device. The list that I am creating in my code behind (that is bound to the listbox) only contains 28 items. I am not sure what the problem is, it seems that everything loads fairly quickly. What I have is as follows:

MainPage.xaml

```
<ScrollViewer>

                    <ListBox Grid.Row="0" x:Name="connectionTileList" Margin="12,0,12,0" toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True">
                        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <toolkit:WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <toolkit:HubTile Title="{Binding TileName}" Margin="6"
                                         Notification="{Binding Notification}"
                                         DisplayNotification="{Binding DisplayNotification}"
                                         Message="{Binding Message}"
                                         GroupTag="{Binding GroupTag}"
                                         Source="{Binding ImageUri}"
                                         Tap="connectionHubTile_Tap">
                                    <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                                        <toolkit:ContextMenu x:Name="connectionMenu">
                                            <toolkit:MenuItem Header="pin to start" Tap="connectionMenuItem_Tap"/>
                                        </toolkit:ContextMenu>
                                    </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                                </toolkit:HubTile>

                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>

                </ScrollViewer>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
List<TileItem> networkTileItems;

public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        CreateConnectionHubTiles();
    }

private void CreateConnectionHubTiles()
    {
        networkTileItems = new List<TileItem>
        {

            new TileItem() { ImageUri = "/Images/Network/temp.png", Title = "Asymmetric DSL", Notification = "not active (what is proper term?)", /*Message = "not active (what is proper term?)"*/ GroupTag = "ConnectionTileGroup", TileName = "Asymmetric DSL", Type = NetworkInterfaceType.AsymmetricDsl  },
                ...

        };

        this.connectionTileList.ItemsSource = networkTileItems;
    }
```

When running, the list only creates the scrolling up effect, whether I try to scroll up or down. How might I be able to fix this issue? Should I load the images in a background thread, or only load a few images at a time while scrolling, or anything else? If so, how could I accomplish this?

Comment: I think that the problem is that you didn't set the height of the list/scrollviewer so it renders itself completely, takimg as much space as it needs (height being much more than 800px) which then causes the scrollviewer to, well, not be scrollable really. if you set the fixed height, you would notice that the scrolling then works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that you're wrapping a `ListBox` in a `ScrollViewer`, and both controls are trying to take the manipulations. Either set

`ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"` on the `ListBox`, to let the outer `ScrollViewer` manage the scrolling, or remove the outer `ScrollViewer` completely.